# TFS 2012 API - Set Version Control Permissions?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to set the various version control permissions of a TFS item via the TFS API. Here is the code I am using that successfully sets the read and checkout permissions for the given folder path:

```
        IIdentityManagementService ims = tpc.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
        TeamFoundationIdentity userIdentity = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
                                                "Guest",
                                                MembershipQuery.None,
                                                ReadIdentityOptions.IncludeReadFromSource);

        ISecurityService ss = tpc.GetService<ISecurityService>();
        SecurityNamespace securityNamespace = ss.GetSecurityNamespace(SecurityConstants.RepositorySecurityNamespaceGuid);

        securityNamespace.SetPermissions(folderPath, userIdentity.Descriptor, RegistryServicePermissions.AllPermissions, 0, true);
```

What I don't understand is the value to use in the 3rd parameter (the "allow" parameter) of SetPermissions in order to set various things such as checkin, manage branch, etc. the MSDN documentation is vary vague.

```
    public abstract AccessControlEntry SetPermissions(
            string token,
            IdentityDescriptor descriptor,
            int allow,
            int deny,
            bool merge
    )
```

The description for the "allow" parameter simply says:

```
    allow
    Type: System.Int32
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of allow should be the value of the exact permission you want to allow on this particular identity eg. VersionedItemPermissions.Read

Since it is an enum it is listed as an int32 since enums to support various entities in TFS ie Build, Version Control, Work Item Tracking etc.

Comment: You can `|` these enum values together to combine permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the int parameter like this:

```
    int allow = (int)Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.Read;
    int deny = (int)(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.AdminProjectRights |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.Checkin |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.CheckinOther |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.PendChange |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.Label |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.ReviseOther |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.LabelOther |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.Lock |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.ManageBranch |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.Merge |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.UndoOther |
                        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions.UnlockOther);
```

Comment: Kudos for actually listing all the available values for this enum.