# How to set TFS version control permissions for NotSet

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I'm trying to use TFS API to configure TFS VC permissions. I'm able to use "Allow" or "Deny" ACEs for a specified group/user on version controlled (VC) folder item. I took help from:
[VCPermissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691924/tfs-2012-api-set-version-control-permissions/14692190#14692190)

However, I'm not able to find how to set "**Not Set**" ACE. This option is used by TFS when you click "**Clear explicit options**" for a user/group from a version control item.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Not set means to have no ACE and optionally to disable inheritance.

Comment: $vcSecurityNamespace = $sec.GetSecurityNamespace([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.SecurityConstants]::RepositorySecurityNamespaceGuid)$vcSecurityNamespace.SetPermissions($teamProjectSC.ServerItem, $tfsGroup.Descriptor, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions]::None, [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.VersionedItemPermissions]::None, $true)

Comment: Can you please provide an example or point me to some links? 
I tried SetPermissions() method of SecurityNamespace (RepositorySecurityNamespaceGuid) with None for Allow parameter and All for Deny parameter.
But when I go back to security screen of VS to view the effects, the group is removed from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set 'Not Set'. To get 'Not Set' for a specified group/user on version controlled (VC) folder item, you may need to delete the permissions by using **PermissionChange.Remove** Property.

Please take a look [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.permissionchange.permissionchange.aspx) for further information about PermissionChange Constructor. Here is a blog about [Update user permissions in source control using TFS API](https://ssinghvi.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/update-user-permissions-in-source-control-using-tfs-api/) for your reference.

Comment: I tried the suggested link but the issues is still same. Once I Deny ALL, the user/group itself disappears. What I want is a way to **UnSet** permissions and not remove user/group. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried PermissionChange.Remove too but it didn't work. Example, if the group has only one permissions set let's say READ before executing my script. In my script I remove the READ permission. The whole group disappears from the configure security screen instead of setting the specific READ permission to **Not Set**